# anchor scroll with angular/ionic breaks layout and scrolling up is not possible anymore

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my code:

```
  if($state.current.name == "list") {
          $scope.scrollToAnchorWithinCurrentPage = function(anchor) {
              $location.hash(anchor);
              var handle = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('img');
              handle.anchorScroll();
    };
      }
```

Somewhere else:

```
$scope.scrollToAnchorWithinCurrentPage('foo');
```

HTML:

```
  <img src="img/list/pfeil-badge.png" ng-hide="!unlocked" id="foo" ng-if="atStreet" class="pfeil-only-badge" alt="">
```

The content scrolls to the anchor, but scrolling up again is not possible anymore.

When i scroll down the app looks like this:

So it's possible to overscroll...

Any help much apreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that i had to change my ion-content to the following:

```
overflow-scroll="true" has-bouncing="true"
```